# How do you correctly wire up dynamically created buttons in Blazor?

Tags: c#, razor, .net-standard, blazor

I'm fairly new to web frontend, but thought it would be great to have toggle buttons for every 'flaw' in a matrix I was displaying (so you can choose a path backtracing up the matrix).

Luckily, I figured out how to make buttons dynamically in Blazor... Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to 'wire' the buttons.

If I was statically making a button, I could say onclick="@(()=>alignment.ChangeArrow(1))" for the first flaw location, replace the 1 with a 2 for the second, etc...

Giving it 1 (instead of i) in the below code snippet makes all the buttons work for the 1st flaw, but if I give it the variable i then it doesn't work at all?

```
@for (int i = 0; i < alignment.FlawList.Count; i++)
{
    <button class="button" style="background-color:@alignment.ReturnColor(i)" onclick="@(()=>alignment.ChangeArrow(i))">@alignment.FlawList[i] @i</button>
}
```

Is there a better Blazor, web way to do what I am talking about?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < alignment.FlawList.Count; i++)
{
   var local_i = i;
    <button class="button" style="background-color:@alignment.ReturnColor(local_i)" onclick="@(()=>alignment.ChangeArrow(local_i))">@alignment.FlawList[local_i] @local_i</button>
}
```

Comment: Whaa!? Awesome, thanks! Do you have a why on this?

It's funny, I was trying all kinds of things similar to this (I guess from past experience), but didn't think quite that local. I was writing a separate function in the component to call the alignment.ChangeArrow.

Is this bad practice, or is this a reasonable way to do it. Works great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This may work with adjustments....no idea on performance etc. Seemed like fun to do anyway. Reminds me of doing Winforms, but I really don't like doing long code behind in WinForms. There's something nice about being able to generate RenderFragments in C#.

---

Place a RenderFragment Tag in the cshtml. (Wherever you need it rendered on the page)

```
@MyFragment
```

Create the Change Arrow method

```
void ChangeArrow(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Changing arrow");
}
```

Generate the RenderFragment Delegate

```
static RenderFragment MyFragment = build =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < alignment.FlawList.Count; i++)
        {
            build.OpenElement(i + 101, "button"); //Open Element
            build.AddAttribute(i + 101, "style",
                $"background-color:{alignment.ReturnColor(i)}");
            build.AddAttribute(i + 101, "onclick", ChangeArrow(i)); // Assign Func to the onclick Attribute
            build.AddContent(i + 101, $"{alignment.FlawList[i]} {i}");
            build.CloseComponent(); //Making sure to close Element
        }
    };
```